# Vista: "connect to a network" does not load (can't set up VPN)

Tags: windows-vista, networking, vpn

I'm trying to connect to my office VPN from home.  One small problem: my home desktop uses Vista (64-bit, Ultimate edition).  On Vista, you're supposed to set up a VPN like so:

- Open the control panel
- Click on Network
- Click on "Connect to a Network"
- Configure a new connection of type "Office"

The problem is, when I click on the link for "Connect to a Network", *nothing happens*.

Can anyone suggest how I should go about troubleshooting this?  (Or am I better off just upgrading to Windows 7?)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's VPN? It could be OpenVPN, which i think is not bundled in WVUE. If you discover its OpenVPN try http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand this comment.  The VPN server at the office is an actual server located on our network.  What I'm trying to use to connect to it is the standard (I think) method in Vista.